# jaxb doesn't generate classes for different elements of the same type

Tags: xml, jaxb

The xsd schema contains two different elements with the same type:

```
<element name="subscriber" type="ns1:CreateSubscriberType"/>
<element name="systemSubscriber" type="ns1:CreateSubscriberType"/>

<complexType name="CreateSubscriberType">
<annotation>
  <documentation>bla bla bla</documentation>
</annotation>
<sequence>
  <element name="Header" type="ns2:DocumentHeader"/>
  <element name="SubscriberDefault" type="ns2:SubscriberDefaultType">
    <annotation>
      <documentation>bla bla</documentation>
    </annotation>
  </element>
</sequence>
</complexType>
```

The xsd schema contains two different elements with the same type:
Then I try to generate classes from this xsd by using maven-jaxb2-plugin and there is no resut. The classes were not generated. If I chanage the type of one of the element it will work fine and 2 classes will be generated. I didn't find explanation in official documentation. Can anybody encountered such a problem and how it could be fixed

Comment: Please don't use phrases like "there is no resut".  Tell us what it *does* do, then explain what you'd like it to do instead.

Comment: The maven plugin should generate separate class for each element.

Comment: No, that's not true, it generates classes for each type.

Answer (score 4):

A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will generate a class for each of the complex types.  This is good because instances of this class can be set on any field/property that corresponds to an attribute/element of that type.  For named complex types the global elements that refer to them will be captured as metadata in the ObjectFactory class.

**schema.xsd**

Below is a slightly simplified version of your XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="subscriber" type="ns1:CreateSubscriberType" />
    <element name="systemSubscriber" type="ns1:CreateSubscriberType" />

    <complexType name="CreateSubscriberType">
        <annotation>
            <documentation>bla bla bla</documentation>
        </annotation>
        <sequence/>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

**XJC Call**

```
xjc -d out -p forum8941337 schema.xsd
```

**CreateSubscriberType**

Below is the class that was generated for the complex type:

```
package forum8941337;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CreateSubscriberType")
public class CreateSubscriberType {

}
```

**ObjectFactory**

The generated `ObjectFactory` class contains two `create` methods annotated with `@XmlElementDecl` these correspond to the two global elements in your XML schema.

```
package forum8941337;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Subscriber_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org", "subscriber");
    private final static QName _SystemSubscriber_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org", "systemSubscriber");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public CreateSubscriberType createCreateSubscriberType() {
        return new CreateSubscriberType();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org", name = "subscriber")
    public JAXBElement<CreateSubscriberType> createSubscriber(CreateSubscriberType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<CreateSubscriberType>(_Subscriber_QNAME, CreateSubscriberType.class, null, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org", name = "systemSubscriber")
    public JAXBElement<CreateSubscriberType> createSystemSubscriber(CreateSubscriberType value) {
        return new JAXBElement<CreateSubscriberType>(_SystemSubscriber_QNAME, CreateSubscriberType.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum8941337;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("forum8941337");
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        CreateSubscriberType subscriberType = new CreateSubscriberType();
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

            // System Subscriber
        JAXBElement<CreateSubscriberType> systemSubscriber = objectFactory.createSystemSubscriber(subscriberType);
        marshaller.marshal(systemSubscriber, System.out);

            // Subscriber
        JAXBElement<CreateSubscriberType> subscriber = objectFactory.createSubscriber(subscriberType);
        marshaller.marshal(subscriber, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<systemSubscriber xmlns="http://www.example.org"/>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<subscriber xmlns="http://www.example.org"/>
```

Comment: As I understood from your answer I should get an instance of 'subscriber' or 'systemSubscriber' from ObjectFactory and JAXB will not generate the separate classes. Is it correct? But my xsd contains another elements with different types and for each element the maven plugin generates separate class. Only for elements with different names but with the same type the plugin isn't generates classes.

Comment: @Mirian - JAXB will also generate classes for anonymous complex types.  If that anonymous type is wrapped in a global element then the JAXB implementation will add an `@XmlRootElement` annotation to that class.

Comment: I spent a weekend reading JSR-222 and looks like I have a problem with maven jaxb plguin but not the xjc compiler. If I generate classes with help of xjc compiler I'll get the same picture as you. But if I use maven plugin(inside it use xjc compiler) I'll get Subscriber.java and SystemSubscriber.java in additional to CreateSubscriberType.java. Could you please tell me is there specific properties for xjc compiler to generate classes for global elements too?

Answer (score 0):

After deeper investigation we found out that global elements are generated when external custom binding is added from xs:dateTime to joda.DateTime. I tested it on xjc compiler:
xjc -extension -b custom-binding.xjb outSchema.xsd.
Is't correct behaviour for JAXB 2.1.10?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by jaxb binding:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="youra.xsd" node="/xs:schema"> 
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name = 'subscriber']">
        <jaxb:class name="SubscriberClass" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name = 'systemSubscriber']">
        <jaxb:class name="SystemSubscriberClass" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```